# Touch Lua + on iPad sys.gettime()

Tags: lua

Anyone who uses this app, could you explain to me what this function does? I assumed it would print the current time in seconds, but that appears otherwise.

```
print(sys.gettime())
```

Comment: which app? Providing a name to the app would help.

Comment: Touch Lua + is the name.

Comment: What do you get for the printed output?

Comment: A large decimal number. Example: 440658324.28168